# How to update the data of some fields in one table based on the data of other field present on other table using LINQ or SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-update

I have the following view and table in my project,

vw_get_arabia_upod_full_details
[image]

arabia_upod_item_avalability_master
[image]

I want to update quantity and the total price present in vw_get_arabia_upod_full_details for each item_id based on maxAllowed in the same table and  availableQuantity present in arabia_upod_item_avalability_master. The availableQuantity is the total no. of quantity that is available. So I need to update quantity for each item checking maxAllowed and assigning maxAllowed (or less than that) to quantity till availableQuantity becomes zero. Could you help me? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where is the view retrieving the maxAllowed field from? I ask because it would seem that modifying the view to use the availableQuantity would be more efficient than copying this value over later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
update vw_get_arabia_upod_full_details 
set
    quantity = your value
    price = ...
from vw_get_arabia_upod_full_details d
join arabia_upod_item_avalability_master m on d.id = m.id
where your condition
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. FYI, Id is different in both the tables. I need to even check availableQuantity and maxAllowed.

Comment: @JavedAhmed: Sure, I've updated my answer. Screenshots are small and database scheme is not clear for me enough, so please elaborate and clarify, or try to insert the code remaining by yourself.